# JAVA RPC server is not working in Ubuntu 10.04 Server Edition

Tags: server, 10.04, rpc

I am facing this weird problem. I have started a RPC server from my Java program in Ubuntu 10.04 server.

But unfortunately I can not access this RPC! The port number at which the RPC is started is a free one.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Does it work when your client is running on the same system?

Do you have a firewall enabled, for examples iptables?

And final question, not related but important: you understand that 10.04 will go out of service next month?

Comment: No it does not work, and the client runs on the same system.